# css animation : slide a div hidden from the side to the center

Tags: html, css

I want to animate some sort of floating *div*.
When the div is in the status 'close' , most of it is hidden on the right of the screen, with only `20px` still visible.

When I click on the visible part, the *div* move to the center of the screen, revealing itself.(it's what I call the status open)

My issue are:

- I only know how center a *div* with `margin:auto`, which do weird stuff when I animate it
- when the div is 'closed', the 'hidden' part create an overflow who add a scrolling. I don't want that
- the *div* have a width who change a lot, depending of the case. Consequently, I cannot use a lot of hard coded value in **CSS**.

Any idea how to do this?
Even a partial solution would help me.

Edit : the solution (thanks to @sonic)

```
.open{
  translateX(-50%);
  left:50%;
}

.close {
  translateX(-20px);
  left:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its too open question to be able to help with 2,3 points, its hard even to say what is the objective and without code, who knows...

Centering div like that:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

you can easly animate those properties.

Comment: It work, thanks ! I will edit my original post to add the implemented solution. I didn't know the combo left + transform for centering stuff.